# Two byte character in a single byte character encoded (ISO-8859-1) HTML document

Tags: php, html, character-encoding, truetype

I learned that **ISO-8859-1** is a single-byte charset.

See the page http://www.manoramaonline.com/cgi-bin/MMOnline.dll/portal/ep/malayalamContentView.do?tabId=11&programId=1073753760&BV_ID=@@@&contentId=15238737&contentType=EDITORIAL&articleType=Malayalam%20News. It is using Malayalam language.

The HTTP header and meta tag tell that it is using **ISO-8859-1** as character-encoding.

But in this page a two byte character (0x201A) is used (http://unicodelookup.com/#%E2%80%9A).

[image]

(copy the character and look up it in http://unicodelookup.com)

```
<div id="articleTitleMal" style="padding-top:10px;">
    <font face= "Manorama" >
         ¼ÈØOVA¢: ÜÍß‚Äí 1.28 ...
    </font>
 </div>
```

How is it possible to use two byte character in the single byte encoding?

Mine is not a curiosity to know that. One of my task is stucked because of not understanding the above issue.

Update: They are using the font www.manoramaonline.com/portal/mmcss/Manorama.ttf and I think some of the character in the Manaorama-font using two byte.

UPDATE2: I tried to convert the document from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 using the below code.

```
<?php
$t = file_get_contents('http://www.manoramaonline.com/cgi-bin/MMOnline.dll/portal/ep/malayalamContentView.do?tabId=11&programId=1073753760&BV_ID=@@@&contentId=15238737&contentType=EDITORIAL&articleType=Malayalam%20News');

// Change the charset info in meta-tag
$t  = str_replace('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $t);

file_put_contents('t.html', utf8_encode($t));
```

That time the above selected character is missing.

[image]

Comment: In this case I would look into the use of a specific font specified here `http://www.manoramaonline.com/portal/mmcss/mmFont.css` ... Font here: www.manoramaonline.com/portal/mmcss/Manorama.ttf

Comment: @jtheman I looked the font. They are using two-byte character for some letters.

Comment: Are you sure that encoding is still on `ISO-8859-1` while you are visiting that page? 'Cause mostly it'll print them as `?` marks.

Comment: @MahanGM visit the page and check the HTTP header and Meta tag. Both tells that it is ISO-8859-1

Comment: You can still HTMLencode the character &#x201A;

Comment: @IesusSonesson I am just user of the website. I cannot change the page.

Comment: Well then, They might have htmlencoded the character ^^

Comment: @IesusSonesson Have a look at its source file. There is no htmlencoded.

Comment: @MahanGM the encoding was not in `ISO-8859-1`. see the accepted answer.

Comment: @HabeebPerwad Yes. I saw it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though the page is declared as ISO-8859-1 encoded in HTTP headers, browsers interpret it as Windows-1252 encoded. This is a longstanding tradition, now being formalized e.g. in the [WHATWG Encoding Standard](http://encoding.spec.whatwg.org).

Thus, when the data contains the byte 82 (hex), it is not taken as a control character (as per ISO 8859-1) but as U+201A “‚” (as per Windows-1252).

However, the page uses font trickery that maps code positions to Malayalam characters according to a special internal, nonstandard encoding. (You can see this if you disable style sheets on the page. All texts become gibberish.) The page is not really meant to contain U+201A “‚” but the byte 82 to which a Malayalam character is assigned in the font.

So you need to preserve the byte as-is to get the same results. A conversion to UTF-8 would break this.

If you wanted to convert the data to Unicode, you would need to find out the internal encoding of the font being used and perform that mapping at the character level.

Comment: Great! You gave more light on the issue. Let me go through the details to find out the solution to my issue.

Comment: Kiitos! The whole point is that the document is not in ISO-8859-1 but in windows-1252. Earlier, I was converting it from ISO-8859-1, now changed to windows-1252. I wasted several hours to tackle the issue. Now solved the issue. I have prepared code for converting the Manorama-font-code to Unicode-code. That is working fine. The problem was i was getting 0x82 for the character, But My mapping-function expects U+201A. I tried to convert the data from ISO-8859-1 instead of windows-1252.